# What are managed modules?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've recently been pushing some ASP.NET MVC 3 and 4 sites to IIS 7 and have had major issues. Usually the fix is to include the following to the Web.Config

```xml
<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
   <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

My question is, why? What is a Managed Module and how do they work with ASP.NET MVC/C#?

EDIT:
After further testing I have discovered that this issue does not exist on Server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5 but the question still stands, what is a managed module and how would I know if I'm using one in my code?

Comment: You wouldn't know. Why wasn't it already set to use them all? I think that's a default. Try making all of the changes you posted _except_ for that one and see if it works, then try making _only_ that change and see if it works.

Comment: IIS usually routes requests based on URL extension to certain modules.  For example, .aspx gets routed to, IIRC, Aspnet_isapi.dll.  But MVC URLs don't have extensions.  So, you have to make sure that managed modules get a chance to act on any URL, not just ones with expected extensions.  `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` lets the MVC routing modules get a crack at extensionless URLs in case they match any of the routes defined in your application.  Remember, IIS7 was a big change, so you had to configure it manually.  7.5 included a fix for this common problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A module is an ASP.Net component that plugs in to some point of the request pipeline; there are many "official" modules, although [you can also code your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx).

[image: IIS listing of modules]

As you can see, modules perform a variety of functions including output caching, various kinds of authorization and authentication, and much more.

---

[It's best not to run *all* managed modules](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html); instead, if you can, figure out what modules a given application or platform needs.  For ASP.Net MVC, that is likely the routing module: `System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule`.